# Python pickling error: TypeError: object pickle not returning list

Tags: python, pickle, astropy, astroquery

I am aware if this very old question [Python pickling error: TypeError: object pickle not returning list. Issue with numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911512/python-pickling-error-typeerror-object-pickle-not-returning-list-issue-with-n) but the only answer given is rather obscure.

This is the code that reproduces the issue in Python 3.6.

```
import pickle
from astroquery.irsa import Irsa
from astropy import units as u

# Query region.
table = Irsa.query_region("m31", catalog="fp_psc", spatial="Cone",
                          radius=.5 * u.arcmin)

# Dump table.
with open('table.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(table, f)

# This is where the issue appears.
with open('table.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    table = pickle.load(f)
```

When trying to load the pickled data, it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/Descargas/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    table2 = pickle.load(f)
  File "/home/gabriel/anaconda3/envs/cat-match/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/table/column.py", line 238, in __setstate__
    super_class.__setstate__(self, state)
  File "/home/gabriel/anaconda3/envs/cat-match/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 5869, in __setstate__
    super(MaskedArray, self).__setstate__((shp, typ, isf, raw))
TypeError: object pickle not returning list
```

How can I get around this?

---

Using [conda](https://www.continuum.io/) you can install the requirements in a Python 3 environment with:

```
conda install astropy
conda install -c astropy astroquery
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace? Maybe the problem can be narrowed down to a simpler case (of unpickling a smaller thing than a whole table), and then circumvented?

Comment: Help me out, by "stack trace" you mean the full traceback (non-programmer here)?

Comment: Yes, the long list of lines leading to the error.

Comment: What versions of numpy and astropy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked answer mentions numpy masked arrays causing trouble when unpickling them. Given that astropy tables may indeed have masked entries (not every object or position may have a value for, e.g., every band or whatever relevant columns), this could indeed be the source of your problem: masked arrays.

The numpy issue trickers shows that problem as well: [Masked array with object dtype doesn't unpickle](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8113). And that appears to be solved in [pull request 8122](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/8122).

Scouring the [release notes for Numpy 1.12.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html) shows this pull request in there. So unless you're already using numpy 1.12, it may be your worth to upgrade numpy.

Comment: I'm using `astropy v1.3`  and `numpy v1.11.3`. For some reason installing `astropy` downgrades `numpy` from `1.12` to that version. I just realized that this morning and opened an issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4817

Comment: @Gabriel I guess Conda uses a hard-coded dependency (judging from the package name), and I assume that is because all their packages have been tested against numpy 1.11. Indeed, there may be other packages in the Conda distribution that can't work with Numpy 1.12 (though unlikely). Numpy 1.12 is pretty recent (and so is Astropy 1.13), so they may not have had the time to fully test Numpy 1.12.

Comment: (cont.) So Conda is supposed to be a stable environment (instead of installing the latest-greatest packages), but may miss the most recent bug fixes. (Apparently, the pickle-masked-arrays is either not regarded as a bug, or the next bug-fix release for the 1.11 series of Numpy is still to appear.)